# The Equal Task - Algorithm Design

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve the Equal problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equal/problem

here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;


public class Solution {
    static List<Integer> memo = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int test = in.nextInt();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        //we initialize a list of memoized values for ho many 1,2,5 choccolates we need to get 1 ... 100
        /*
        we have 1, 2 and 5 to add
        if k<=2 then k=1
        if k>2 and k<5 then n[k] = n[k-2]+1
        if k==5 then k=1
        if k > 5 then n[k] = n[k-5]+1
        */
        memo.add(1);
        memo.add(1);
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
            if(i==4){
                memo.add(1);
            }
            if(i>1 && i<4){
                memo.add(memo.get(i-2)+1);
            }
            if(i>4){
                memo.add(memo.get(i-5)+1);
            }  
        }
        //System.out.println(memo.toString());
        for (int i=0;i<test;i++){
            int val[] = new int[n];
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
                val[j]=in.nextInt();
            }
          //we sort the values in order to start from the minimum
          Arrays.sort(val);
          //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(val));
          calculateOperations(val);

        }
    }

    //we extend at runtime the memoized values if they are not enough
    public static int computeCount(int val){
        if(val==0){
            return 0;
        }
        int ml = memo.size();
        if(val<=ml){
            return memo.get(val-1);
        }else{
            for (int i=ml-1;i<val;i++){
            if(i==4){
                memo.add(1);
            }
            if(i>1 && i<4){
                memo.add(memo.get(i-2)+1);
            }
            if(i>4){
                memo.add(memo.get(i-5)+1);
            }  
            }
            return memo.get(val-1);
        }
    }


    // 1 1 3 5 9
    // 2 2 4 6 9

    public static int [] addChoccolate(int [] values,int val,int no){
        for (int k=0;k<values.length;k++){
            if(k!=no){
            values[k] = values[k]+val;
            }
        }
        return values;
    }

    public static int findDelta(int [] values){
        int s1 = values[0];
        for (int k=1;k<values.length;k++){
            if(values[k]!=s1){
                return k;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void calculateOperations(int val[]){
        int count =0;
        int delta = findDelta(val);
        while(delta>0){
            count += computeCount(val[delta]-val[0]);
            val = addChoccolate(val,val[delta]-val[0],delta);
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(val));
            Arrays.sort(val);
            delta = findDelta(val);
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

it works for the input

```
1
5
1 3 5 5 9
```

in fact it print out `8` that is right since it can be shown that from the starting state

[1,3,5,5,9] we can add 2 to all but the 2nd and get [3, 3, 7, 7, 11]

then we can add two times 2 (4) to all but the 3rd and get [7, 7, 7, 11, 15]

then we can add two times 2 (4) to all but the 4th and get [11, 11, 11, 11, 19]

and finally add 1 time 5, one time 2 and one time 1 (8) to all but the last one [19, 19, 19, 19, 19]

summing app these operations we get:

1 +2 +2 +3 = 8

**However**: I can't see why it doesn't work for the HackerRank tests

Comment: but maybe it can be done in less than 8 steps?

Comment: For which input data it doesn't work? What's the expected result? What's the actual result?

Comment: The example [1,3,5,5,9] giving 8 is correct. The algorithm that came to my mind will be around 20 lines of code and run in O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest a problem reduction.  First of all, let's parametrize the three choices into one:

> Choose one colleague; give **N** chocolates to every other colleague,
>   for N in {1, 2, 5}.

Now, for the reduction:

> Choose one colleague; give **N** chocolates to every other colleague,
>   for **N** in {1, 2, 5}.  Now, *everyone* eats exactly **N** chocolates.

Which converts to

> Take **N** chocolates from any one colleague; for **N** in {1, 2, 5}. Negative totals are allowed.

Memoizing here is pretty easy: it's the coin change problem with coins of 5, 2, 1 units.

You have a list ***Q*** of chocolate quantities.

- task: find the fewest number of transactions to give everyone the same quantity.
- Sub-task: find **K** to minimize quantity of coins needed over the values {***Q***[i] - **K**}

*Observation*: with the given denominations, making minimal change is trivial: use 5 to exhaustion, then 2 to exhaustion, then a 1 if needed.

*Lemma*: if **m** is the smallest value in ***Q***, **K** will be in the range [**m**-4, **m**]

**ALGORITHM**

1. Find **m**, the minimum value of ***Q***
2. For each value of **K** in [**m**-4, **m**]

   - For each element of ***Q***, compute the coin-change count for ***Q*** - **K**.
   - sum those counts

You now have five sums; the minimum of those five is your answer.

Comment: in my example Q = [1,3,5,5,9]  so  m = 1 so the range is [-3,1] ?

Comment: Right.  Any solution that goes to -4 or below will have a **5** in the "coin change" for every element.  This means that there will be a better solution at that value + 5.  Any value grater than 1 will not include the first element.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have now a clear understanding of the problem and I will try to write it down in the easiest possible (to me) way.

As mentioned by @Prune adding to all but the ith elements means substracting from the ith.

Also consider that the point here is to bring all the individuals to the same value.

Now if we sort the elements in an ascending way we may want to find the minimum number of steps (subtracting 1,2,5) to take each individual to the value of the first one (the minimum possible).

However this sometimes lead tu a sub-optimal solution. Let me make some example:

if we start from [1 3 6] we can subtract 2 from the second element and go to [1 1 6] then we can subtract 5 to the third and go to [1 1 1]. In this case the solution is 2 and it is right.

However in this case [1 5 5] we need to subtract 2 times 2 from the second and from the third element in order to have [1 1 1]. In this case the solution would be 4 steps. But it is not the minimum possible. 
The minimum possible is actually to remove 1 from the first element and go to [0 5 5] then to remove 5 from the second and from the third elements for a total of 3 steps. Which is the right one.

This is because we need one step to subtract 5 but we need two steps to remove 3 and 4 choccolates.

So the idea here is that we might need to remove 'something' from the ninimum element (values[0]) in order to maximize the number of elements in the list that are distant a multiple of five from it.

How much is this 'something'? we do not know so we need to evaluate all the possibilities with `values[0]= values[0], values[0]=values[0]-1, values[0]=values[0]-2, values[0]=values[0]-3, values[0]=values[0]-4`. 
we only need to remove from 0 to 4 because we will certainly find a 5 multiplier.

consider for instance [1 9 9] if we don't subtract anything to the first element we need to subtract 1,2,5 (8) from the second and the third which means 6 steps. If we try with values[0]=values[0]-1 we have [0 9 9] which means subtracting 2,2,5 (9) from the second and from the third which, again, means 6 steps plus 1 (the subtraction from the first), so 7 steps. 
However if we try with values[0]=values[0]-2 we have [-1 9 9]. In this case we just need to subtract 2 times 5 (10) from the second and the third elements to have [-1 -1 -1]. This means 4 steps plus one (the first -2 subtraction) so 5 steps which is the best possible solution.